# Websocket channel stream no longer updates after closing the sink and reconnecting

Tags: flutter, dart, websocket, flutter-dependencies, dart-async

I am currently using a websocket channel to implement a chat api, the websocket sink and stream work just fine for the most part, that is until i try to log out. I have it so that when I log out i close the channel using channel?.sink.close(), after that, whenever I log back in, i reconnect to the channel and re-declare the value of channel, then after I do that my channel sink still works just fine and i can add to it whenever, however the stream no longer updates or notifies me of the new messages.

I've tried changing how I approach the websocket stream, using it without asBroadcastStream(), saving it in it's own variable as a broadcast stream, and then add a listener that could tell me if it errored or is finished. however after closing the sink and then reconnecting, the stream doesn't update whatsoever.

below is the important code snippets.

```
BlocBuilder<MessageBloc, MessageState>(
  builder: (BuildContext context, MessageState messageState) {
    if (messageState is ListenedMessageState) {
      messageController = messageState.messageController;
      messageStream = messageState.messageController!.stream
          .asBroadcastStream();
      messageStream!.listen((event) {
        print('stream event: $event');
      }, onDone: () {
        print('stream done.');
      }, onError: (e, s) {
        print('stream errored');
        print(e);
        print(s);
      });
      print('controller: $messageController');
    }
    return StreamBuilder<dynamic>(
        stream: messageStream,
        builder: (context, sp) {
          print(sp.data);
          if (sp.hasData) {
            _addToMessageList(sp.data);
          }....
```

```
 @override
  Future<void> cancelListenMessage() async {
     await channel?.sink.close();
  }

  @override
  Future<void> initializeWebSocket() async {
    channel = WebSocketChannel.connect(Uri.parse('ws://13.48.221.106:8080'));
    await channel!.ready.whenComplete(
        () => print('Websocket chat channel successfully connected'));
    // channel!.stream.asBroadcastStream().listen((event) {
    //   print('current stream event: $event');
    // });
  }
```

```
Future<MessageState?> _listenMessageSuccessOrFailure(
      Either<Failure, WebSocketChannel> result, List<String> chatIds) async {
    return result.fold((l) => ListenedMessageState(messageController: null),
        (r) async {
      try {
        final StreamController _controller1 =
            StreamController<dynamic>.broadcast();

        _controller1.addStream(r.stream);

        await _showNotification(_controller1, chatIds);

        return ListenedMessageState(messageController: _controller1);
      } catch (_) {
        print(
            'Failed to broadcast stream, mightve been already listened to....');
        return null;
      }
    });
  }
```